# how to open published project on github in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, github

To push my project on GitHub I installed GitHub for windows.

1. Created New Repository in GitHub for windows
2. Then I `Published` and then `sync` (from github for windows)
3. Opened my project in Visual Studio. Then `Build` > `Publish project_name`
4. Created new profile.
5. Changed publish method to `File system` Then published.

Now my github project contains these files.

[image]

There is no `.sln` file. How can I open this project in visual studio?

Comment: check your **.gitignore** file, remove **.sln** if it is enlisted in it.

Comment: This is a published folder and is used for deploying your application on IIS I dont think you can use this to develop the application itself

Comment: @Mozfox `.gitignore` does not contain `.sln`

Comment: @Reddy it means once a website is deployed we cannot make changes?

Comment: They are two different things, We use visual studio to develop applications, when its ready we publish the application, This published folder is used in deployment. So you see the difference

Comment: use command  **git add project.sln** to add file manually and commit.

Comment: @IrfanWattoo what are you using **github for Windows** or **Visual Studio Git Plugin**

Comment: @Mozfox I am using `github for windows`

Comment: @Reddy what is its alternative? I want to make changes in project and then push them to github.

Comment: your comment `3) Opened my project in Visual Studio. Then Build > Publish project_name` says you have a project opened already in visual studio right. why are you not able to make changes there and publish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is I cannot open published project in visual studio. To make changes I opened the project through which I have published. I  Made changes over there and then published again.

Then I open github for windows and commit changes.